# How do i add specific item in a list to another list?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, defaultlistmodel

I am having problems with my program. I for some reason can't get items from my one list to another list.

```
defaultListModel model1 = new DefaultListModel();
    DefaultListModel model2 = new DefaultListModel();
    //check an item is selected from listbox
    if (lstlibrary.getSelectedIndex() != -1) {
        int position;
        position = array1.indexOf(lstlibrary.getSelectedValue());
        array2.add(array1.get(position));
        array1.remove(position);    

  //move array to listbox model
        for (String value1 : array1) {
            model1.addElement(value1);
        }
        lstlibrary.setModel(model1);

        for (String value2 : array2) {
            model1.addElement(value2);
        }
        lstlibrary.setModel(model2);
```

This is what my teacher told me to do and i cant get it to work out. I have tried everything and i have no idea what to do, I'm kinda new at all this so if anyone could help me out that would be great!

Comment: Netbeans doesn't have anything to do with this.

Comment: i'm using netbeans for this...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you trying to set model2 to the same list that you the read selected item. You must have two list, for example lstlibrary1 and lstlibrary2
and try moving items from lstlibrary1 to lstlibrary2
so change the last lines from this

```
 for (String value2 : array2) {
        model1.addElement(value2);
    }
    lstlibrary.setModel(model2);
```

to this

```
for (String value2 : array2) {
        model2.addElement(value2);
    }
    lstplaylist.setModel(model2);
```

if the second list object name is lstplaylist
also in the second for loop you must use model2 instead of model1

===============================

## update

try to change these functions to solve the problem

for btnToPlaylistMouseClicked() change the last two for-loop to this

```
// refreshing lstlibrary to remove selected name
for (String value1 : array1) {
        model1.addElement(value1);// adding elements to model1
    }
    lstlibrary.setModel(model1);// using model1 for lstlibrary


//refreshing lstplaylist to add new selected name
    for (String value2 : array2) {
        model2.addElement(value2);// adding elements to model2
    }
    lstplaylist.setModel(model2);// using model2 for lstplaylist
```

also use these for-loops for btnRemoveMouseClicked() too.
you have a problem there too.

Comment: Thanks, it's working a bit better but not totally working. But i didnt put in what that problem was anyway.

Comment: send your complete jframe code to check what is the other problems

Comment: I added the rest of my coding, if there is anything else you need with it to maybe help it, just let me know! ans thank you

Comment: you said that "for some reason cant get items from my one list to another list", I can not see where you use that another list in your code, what is its variable name?

Comment: my first list is lstlibrary and the other list is lstplaylist.

Comment: change your for-loops as i mentioned above.

Comment: could i ask you one more thing though, i want to randomize the lstplaylist and i cant get that to work either. Im not that great at using arrays haha

Comment: that is very easy, you have it. just copy the content of your btnSortMouseClicked() function to your btnRandomMouseClicked() function and then change the Collections.sort(array2); line to Collections.shuffle(array2);, it must working, and please select the best answer at the end, i need those points.

Comment: Thank you so much, idk how i missed that haha, i made you're the best answer and thanks so much for the help!!!